# DNN menu control - how to change content? Dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

I just inherited a DotNetNuke project and I'm in the database and FTP part. I just want to change the contents of the menu but I can't find any documentation on how to do this .Just .. one ... link

It's a SolPartMenu and I've searched the DB and all the site files. Dammit all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Login as Host or admin.

Under the admin menu there is pages, from there you can edit the herarchy of the pages.
In addition you can select a page and use the edit action to edit the page settings allowing you to set the "show in menu" checkbox how you wish.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that by logging in
as Host I can view the pages hierarchy and within those are the levels of menu.